# Embed a word document into a aspx page using c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to embed a word document into a aspx page which should be runnable in the web page itself  while running the aspx page.Can please help me to sort out this problem.

thanks in advance.
Arun.

Comment: Duplicate question?? Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367311/embed-a-word-document-in-c

Answer (score 0):

This might be work a look http://www.officelive.com/en-GB/

Comment: okay thanks for your reply. but i want to open my word document in web page of my own created. Arun...

Comment: Do all clients have Word installed?