# How can I reference a .dotx resource in VB.NET? (Visual Studios Pro)

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2013, ms-word, embedded-resource

I have a program that requires the use of a file with the extension .dotx. Right now I have it as a resource in the solution. With the following code, instead directly using "C:\letterhead.dotx" I want to use the file I have as an 'Embedded Resource'. I tried the following.

```
        Dim oWord As Word.Application
        Dim oDoc As Word.Document
        oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        oWord.Visible = False
                'Works:
                oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add("C:\Letterhead.dotx")
                'Does not work:
                oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(My.Resources.Letterhead)
                'Does not work:
                oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(My.Resources.ResourceManager.BaseName & "\Letterhead.dotx")
```

I am aware that all of those are returning the wrong values and not what I want. I just don't want to force anyone, using this, to put the Letterhead file in a specific place on their computer before running it. I'm sure there's a simple solution, I just don't know it.

Solution:

For all of those (just me) that are also having this problem, all you have to do is the following to write the embedded file to C:\ -

```
        Try
            File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Letterhead.dotx", My.Resources.Letterhead)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to write to C:\", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
```

Comment: There isn't a simple solution. When you make a file an embedded resource, it compiles the file inside your EXE. There is no application in the world (like Word) that is going to decompile your exe and look for an embedded resource then open that file. You need to do a little more work by writing your embedded resource to a physical file and then using that file and location for opening in Word. How to do this is a whole other issue. Not easy but can be done with a little thinking outside the box, ingenuity and google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely store a Word document in a .NET assembly in an embedded resource, and it's fairly trivial to extract it.  However, if you want to open a Word document, the steps would be:

1. Extract the embedded resource to a bytestream
2. Write the bytestream to a disk (temp folder, perhaps?) as a "doc" or "docx" file
3. Open that file from disk with Word

...which is quite a bit more work than just including a Word document with the software.  Unless you have a very compelling reason to do this with an embedded resource, I would just include the Word document with the application.

If you want some more details, check out [Aseem Gautam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213469/aseem-gautam)'s answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367311/embed-a-word-document-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Worked like a charm. I did my own variation on that because I wasn't doing C#, but that's what I did! Thanks